# What kind of a pushbutton is this?

Tags: schematics, symbol

[image: the pushbutton]

It's probably a pushbutton, but what does that arrow represent?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SS1 a selector switch symbol in PLC design logic.

and LS1 is a limit switch, and PS1 is the pressure sensor switch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Deepak, do you know what the PS1 and LS1 symbols specify?

Comment: LS is low sensor switch

Comment: Hi Deepak, It has nothing to do with PLC logic. A PLC ladder diagram would only show 'NO' & NC' contacts. These switch and relay symbols would be used only in the wiring diagram for the PLC I/O modules. Also 'LS' is the letter symbol for 'Limit Switch' and not 'Low Sensor Switch'.

Comment: @vu2nan thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: You are most welcome, Deepak.

Answer (score 3):

The main diagram referred to is an electrical 'relay logic' circuit diagram (also known as a ladder diagram, based on its resemblance to a ladder), drawn as per ANSI standards.

The letter symbols used are 'PB' - Push Button Switch, 'CR' - Control Relay, PL - Pilot Lamp, 'PS' - Pressure switch, 'SOL' - Solenoid Valve, 'LS' - Limit Switch and 'SS' - Selector Switch.

The graphical symbol in question is that of a selector switch, depicting a contact open in one position, which would be closed in the other position.

[image]

Here's the graphical symbol of a 2 contact, 2 position selector switch, with one contact being 'open' and the other 'closed' in one position and vice versa in the other position.

[image]

Comment: ''The graphical symbol in question is that of a selector switch, depicting a contact open in one position, which would be closed in the other position'' surely you mean a 'normally open' switch ?

Comment: @Graham Stevenson, There's a subtle difference. 'NO' & 'NC' only relate to a default position e.g. an unactuated push button switch or a de-energised relay. A selector switch has no default position.

Comment: Looking at PB1 and PB2 is it not obvious that PB1 is normally open and PB2 is normally closed ? That is their resting, non-activated or default condition. They aren't whatever you mean by a 'selector switch'. To me a selector switch might be a rotary switch that always has one way connected.

Comment: @Graham Stevenson, The switch being referred to is SS1 and it's a rotary selector switch.

Comment: OK, what 'selects' SS1 ? Some actuator presumably which is not shown. The 2 contacts of SS1 are still 'normally open' until selected.

Comment: @Graham Stevenson, It's a rotary selector switch with a knob, as per ANSI standards. Here's another example of a 3 position rotary selector switch, to select between functions 'Manual', 'Off' or 'Auto', one pole of which is used to light indicator lamps for 'Manual' or 'Auto' selection . https://www.industrial-electronics.com/images/imc7e_2-32.jpg  . No contact in such a selector switch can be designated as 'NO' or 'NC' since there is no default position.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to add some more info.

In normal nomenclature, PB1, PS1 and SS1 are called 'normally open' as can be seen on the diagram for the 'non operational' condition of the switches.

LS1 is formed of 2 poles that function as a 'changeover switch'.

PB2 is 'normally closed' i.e. push to open.